# How to run a linear model on a certain group of respondents?

Tags: r, tidyverse, linearmodels

I am trying to run a linear model, but only on a certain group of respondents. I found sample code online that said to use the gapminder function to isolate the group of respondents. Here, I only want to include respondents who have a value of 1 in the party column. I followed the sample code I found online,

```
library("tidyverse")
library("gapminder")
dems <- filter(gapminder, 
               + dfp_clean$party == 1)
dem_model <- lm(scale_masc_index ~ ice, data = dems)
summary(dem_model)
```

but I keep getting this error

```
Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
x Input `..1` must be of size 1704 or 1, not size 17723.
ℹ Input `..1` is `+dfp_clean$party == 1`.
```

I tried running

```
rlang::last_error()
```

to see where the error occurred, but it said the same thing as before.

Answer (score 0):

You've not quite got the inputs right in your filter function.

It should look like this:

```
dems <- filter(gapminder, party == 1)
```

Comment: ```> dems <- filter(gapminder, party == 1)
Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
x Input `..1` must be of size 1704 or 1, not size 17723.
ℹ Input `..1` is `party == 1`.```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want your dems dataframe to contain rows from the dfp_clean dataframe? If so, that should be the first argument in the filter function.

```
library("tidyverse")
dems <- filter(dpf_clean, party == 1)
```

The filter function assumes that party is a column in the dpf_clean dataframe (or whatever you put as the first argument) so running the below code will return identical results:

```
library("tidyverse")
dems <- filter(dpf_clean, dpf_clean$party == 1)
```

If this doesn't work, it may be that your dpf_clean dataframe doesn't have a "party" column that it can use to filter rows. If you type:

```
colnames(dpf_clean)
```

you can get a list of all of the columns in that dataframe. If party appears in that list, the code should work.

It looks like the gapminder package just contains data, not any functions, so it doesn't seem like you should need that package to run this line of code. Maybe the tutorial you were looking at was using